# Mazda 3 (2006) passenger seat will not recline anymore

Tags: mazda

I have a Mazda 3 (2006) and the passenger seat will not recline anymore.

I can reach under and feel that a wire which I believe should be 'pulled back' is loose.  Pulling it does nothing so (does not pull out any further),  I assume the other end is where the problem is.

For now it would be good enough if I can just one time manually change the recline position.

I just don't know where the other end is or how to get to it.

Any ideas?

df

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my 1999 Mazda 323 just yesterday. For me, the problem was that I had pulled the back all the way forward for loading (which requires you to pull on lever on the back itself). When I pulled up the seat again, I apparently pulled it somewhat diagonally which made it stuck.

I solved this problem by getting another pair of hands so we could pull both levers simultaneously and adjust the back diagonally back to normal.